# Force rejecting Angular $http call

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am using `$http` to make a call. Based on the successful result of the call I may decided to throw an error/reject and have it trickle down to the next call as an error. However if an error is thrown it just halt the process. How can I force the $http promise to reject without wrapping it in some $q code?

```
// A service

angular.module('app').factory('aService', function ($http, config) {    
  return {
    subscribe: function (params) {
      return $http({
        url: '...'
        method: 'JSONP'
      }).then(function (res) {
        // This is a successful http call but may be a failure as far as I am concerned so I want the calling code to treat it so.
        if (res.data.result === 'error') throw new Error('Big Errror') 
      }, function (err) {
        return err
      })
    }
  }
})


// Controller
 aService.subscribe({
  'email': '...'
}).then(function (result) {

}, function (result) {
    // I want this to be the Big Error message. How do I get here from the success call above?
})
```

In the above code I would like the Big Error message to end up as a rejected call. However in this case it just dies with the error. This is how I handle things in say Bluebird but it's a no go here.

Comment: in either case just return a rejected promise return $q.reject('reason').

Comment: Ah yes I was thinking I had to wrap it in a `$q.deferred` but yes that works. You can post that as an answer if you wanna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ti continue the Chain  in a rejected state just return a rejected promise `$q.reject('reason')` from your $http result something like

`$http.get(url).then(
    function (response){
      if(something){
        return $q.reject('reason');
      }
      return response;
    }
  )`

That way you'll get a a rejected promise and can react to it  even when the api call is successful.